# How to create mock instance of Autowired component in Vert.x

Tags: junit, vert.x, junit5, vertx-verticle

I am trying to create mock instance of the class which is `autowired` inside `Verticle` but I am getting it as a null. For synchronous code the way which works is looking not useful for `Vert.x`.

Verticle is:

```java
    @Component
    public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle{

    @Autowired
    private ServiceExecutor serviceExecutor;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        super.start();
        vertx.eventBus().<String>consumer("address.xyz").handler(handleRequest());
    }

    private Handler<Message<String>> handleRequest() {
        return msg -> {
            getSomeData(msg.body().toString())
            .setHandler(ar -> {
                if(ar.succeeded()){
                    msg.reply(ar.result());
                }else{
                    msg.reply(ar.cause().getMessage());
                }
             });
        };
    }

    private Future<String> getSomeData(String inputJson) {
        Promise<String> promise = Promise.promise();
        String data = serviceExecutor.executeSomeService(inputJson); // Getting NPE here. serviceExecutor is coming as null when trying to create mock of it using Mockito.when.
        promise.complete(data);
        return promise.future();    
     }
  }
```

Dependent component is:

```java
@Component
public class ServiceExecutor {

    public String executeSomeService(String input){
        return "Returning Data";
    }
}
```

Test case is:

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.Async;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MyVerticleTest {

    @Mock
    private ServiceExecutor serviceExecutor;

    private Vertx vertx;

    @Before
    public void setup(TestContext ctx){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Async async = ctx.async();
        this.vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(MyVerticle.class.getName(), h -> {
            if(h.succeeded()){
                async.complete();
            }else{
                ctx.fail();
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test_consumption(TestContext ctx) {
        Async async = ctx.async();
        when(serviceExecutor.executeSomeService(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("Returning Data");
        vertx.eventBus().request("address.xyz","message", h ->{
            if(h.succeeded()){
                ctx.assertEquals("Returning Data",h.result().body().toString());
                async.complete();
            }else{
                ctx.fail(h.cause());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Above Test Case works well if I don't use `autowired` instance to call a method to get the date. But if used it (which I must do to get the data), it is giving NPE at `MyVerticle->getSomeData()` method when trying to use `serviceExecutor` object as a mock. This approach works very well for Synchronous code flow but for `Vert.x` looks like it won't help. So need help here to mock the `autowired` instance `serviceExecutor` inside `Verticle`.

Comment: You can use `@InjectMocks private MyVerticle myVerticle;`  and something like `vertx.deployVerticle(myVerticle, options, ctx.asyncAssertSuccess());` in setup method instead of lamda expression. Will this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor in your MyVerticle

```
public MyVerticle(ApplicationContext context) {
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
}
```

and deploy your verticle something like vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle(context),...

I have application context while deploying the verticle and thats what I am passing in the constructor. Check if this works for you.